# Unity Mirror, client doesn't execute server cmd

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

When player press key if he touched other player he try markPlayer

When client touched host-player, log only "CmdServer" and stop, but on host-player, its full complete all methods and change color on another character;

Client code

```
        //somemovementClass
        private void TriggerEntered(PlayerContext playerContext)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Collided with {playerContext.name}");
            CmdServer(playerContext);
        }

        [Command]
        public void CmdServer(PlayerContext playerContext)
        {
            Debug.Log($"CmdServer");
            playerContext.MarkPlayer();
        }
```

```
        // PlayerContext.cs

        [SyncVar(hook = nameof(OnPlayerGetDamage))]
        private bool wasDamaged; 

        [Server]
        public void MarkPlayer()
        {
            Debug.Log("On Server");
            wasDamaged = true;
        }

        private void OnPlayerGetDamage(bool oldState, bool newState)
        {
            Debug.Log("On Get Damage");
            cashedMaterial.color = Color.red;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried instead of the SyncVar and hook directly use a `ClientRpc`? I never trusted those syncvars ^^

Comment: also in general before calling `CmdServer` you should check if this object is the local authority otherwise you can't invoke a command anyway

Comment: I think I solved the problem, although I'm not sure that the problem was specifically in this, but still, I didn't use the Monobehaviour class and hoped that the command would compile correctly, because usually mirror throws errors if something is wrong. I just moved the cmd method to a separate class from networkbehaviour

Comment: afaik `NetworkBehaviour` **is** an extension of `MonoBehaviour` so sounds strange that this should be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem, although I'm not sure that the problem was specifically in this, but still, I didn't use the Monobehaviour class and hoped that the command would compile correctly, because usually mirror throws errors if something is wrong. I just moved the cmd method to a separate class from networkbehaviour